# Showing RDLC report inside asp.net mvc 5 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, reporting, rdlc, microsoft-reporting

I have created following view form to filter results ,

[image]

also I have created following aspx web-form to generate report

[image]

Now I want to once I click **Generate Report** button in view form(1st image) I should be able to pass parameters to text boxes

1. Type
2. Category
3. Subsidary
4. Country
5. Date

generate results in web-form and show Microsoft report wizard(RDLC) like 2nd image .

I have done these things separately, I want to link those together

Comment: I don't really see a problem here... The view form on the first screenshot works? As in, you are able to pass variables from the filter and fill the table below it? Then you should have no problem to pass them as parameters to your reporter. Perhaps [this walktrough](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251669.aspx) might be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

### 1

Create a model with the filter properties but add a datatable for dataset in report.rdlc for example

```
public class paramsModel
{
    public string typeRep {get; set;}
    public DateTime dateRep {get; set;}
    public DataTable dataReport {get; set;}
}
```

### 2

In your Controller create the ActionResult for the View

```
    public ActionResult showReport()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult showReport(paramsModel paramsRep)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            paramsRep.dataReport = LocalData.GetDataFromDb(paramsRep.typeRep, paramsRep.dateRep);               
        }

        return View(paramsRep);
    }
```

### 3

In your View

```
@model yourproyect.models.paramsModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Report page";
    var settings = new ControlSettings
    {
        UseCurrentAppDomainPermissionSet = true,
        EnableHyperlinks=true
    };
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Report filters</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.typeRep , new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.typeRep , ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(model => model.typeRep , ViewData).EditFormatString, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.typeRep )
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dateRep , new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.dateRep , ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(model => model.dateRep , ViewData).EditFormatString, new { @class = "form-control datepicker" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dateRep )
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  

}

<div>
    @if (Model != null)
    {
        <div >
         @Html.MvcReportViewer("Reports/YourReport.rdlc").ProcessingMode(ProcessingMode.Local).LocalDataSource("DataSet1", Model.dataReport).ControlSettings(settings).Attributes(new { Style = "width:100%; border:none; height: 87vh;" }).Method(FormMethod.Post)
        </div>
    }       
</div> 

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            dateformat: "@System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern.ToLower()",
            language: "es",
            autoclose: true,
            showAnim: 'blind',
            highlightWeek: true
        }); //Initialise any date pickers
    </script>
}
```

Comment: possible post the full detail as i tried but failed